# I want to remove the columns after colspan in dataTable

Tags: jquery, html-table, datatables

How to use colspan in dataTable?
I want the colspan in the uraian column with the condition that if the column after it is zero, then // Add COLSPAN attribute

`$('td:eq(3)', row).attr('colspan', 6);`

**I want to remove the columns after it**
This is the result I tried: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzKzd.png

This is my code :

```
table = $('#dataTable').DataTable( {
    "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]],
    "destroy": true,
    "paging": true,
    "sorting": true,
    "responsive": true,
    "ajax": {
        "type": "POST",
        "url": "modul/mod_instrumen/elemen_action.php",
        "data": {jenis:jenis},
        "timeout": 120000,
        "dataSrc": function (json) {
            if(json !== null){
                return json
            } else {
                return "";
            }
            
        }
    },
    columns: [ 
        {
            "name": "No", "title": "No",
            "data": null,
            render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                return meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1;
            }
        },
        {
            "data": null,
            "name": "#",
            "title": "#",
            "width": "120px",
            "render": function (data, row, type, meta) {
                return `<button id="`+data.id+`" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm edit_data" title="Update Data"><i class="fa-solid fa-square-pen"></i></button>
                <button id="`+data.id+`" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm view_data" title="Lihat Data"> <i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                <button id="`+data.id+`" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm hapus_data" title="Hapus Data"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can"></i></button>
                `;
            }
        },
        {data: 'kode', name: 'kode', title: 'Kode'},    
        {data: 'uraian', name: 'uraian', title: 'Uraian'},  
        {data: 'fakta_dan_analisis', name: 'fakta_dan_analisis', title: 'Fakta dan Analisis'}, 
        {data: 'regulasi', name: 'regulasi', title: 'Regulasi'}, 
        {data: 'observasi', name: 'observasi', title: 'Observasi'}, 
        {data: 'wawancara', name: 'wawancara', title: 'Wawancara'}, 
        {data: 'simulasi', name: 'simulasi', title: 'Simulasi'},
        {data: 'dokbuk1', name: 'dokbuk1', title: 'Dokumen Bukti'}
        
    ],
    createdRow: function(row, data, dataIndex){
        
        let text = data.fakta_dan_analisis;
        //let panjang = text.length;
        if(text == ''){
            // Add COLSPAN attribute
            $('td:eq(3)', row).attr('colspan', 6);

            // Hide required number of columns
            // next to the cell with COLSPAN attribute
            $('td:eq(4)', row).css('display', 'none');
            $('td:eq(5)', row).css('display', 'none');
            $('td:eq(6)', row).css('display', 'none');
            $('td:eq(7)', row).css('display', 'none');
            $('td:eq(8)', row).css('display', 'none');
            // Update cell data
            //this.api().cell($('td:eq(3)', row)).data(data.uraian);
        }
    },
});
```

This is the result I tried: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzKzd.png

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: DataTables expects you to have a [well-formed HTML table](https://datatables.net/manual/installation#HTML) - but note also where it states: "_while DataTables supports `colspan` and `rowspan` in the table's header and footer, they are not supported in the table's `tbody` and **must not be present**._" (Emphasis mine.)